# Apache log4php LoggerAppenderDailyFile maxBackupIndex

Tags: log4php

In Apache's log4php **LoggerAppenderDailyFile** appender, is it possible to limit the number of backup files kept?

Like what is done with the **LoggerAppenderRollingFile** appender's *maxBackupIndex* parameter.

See: https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/daily-file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No configuration available by default from Log4j.

https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/daily-file.html
shows the configuration maxBackupIndex is not available for LoggerAppenderDailyFile unlike  LoggerAppenderRollingFile (https://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/appenders/rolling-file.html)

One hack is to create a crontab entry to do the same
see this link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/